# Why won't Android Studio find my resources?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Android Studio code inspection seems to not find any of the project-specific resources.

For example my styles.xml

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Holo.Theme.Light.DarkActionBar">
  </style>

  <!-- Application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
  </style>
</resources>
```

Marks the second AppBaseTheme red and says: "Cannot resolve symbol 'AppBaseTheme'".

The app compiles and runs without problems but I don't have any code-completion on resources. The inspection seems to find the ActionBarSherlock resources and HoloEverywhere resources (e.g. Holo.Theme.Light.DarkActionBar, auto-complete works too) though.

build.gradle of the app (sub)project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    //compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile project(':abs-library')
    compile project(':he-library')
    compile project(':he-addons:slider')
    compile project(':he-addons:preferences')
    // using a custom repo here
    compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r13'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            // abs-res, he-res are symlinks to ../abs-library/res
            // and ../he-library/res 
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'abs-res', 'he-res']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 58):

The first thing I would try is *File > Invalidate Caches\Restart > Invalidate and Restart*.

This has fixed all resource issues I've ever had with Android Studio.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but then I was trying to get an Eclipse import working...

Comment: Not necessary to restart, you can just do `Invalidate` and close then reopen the project. This is a bit quicker than restarting.

Answer (score 7):

Try with the button "Sync Project with Gradle Files" in the tools bar (the green circle with blue arrow), it worked for me

You can also force the sync changing something in your gradle (Sync button will popup and you should click it) and then reverting the changes and clicking again "Sync"

Answer (score 4):

You have a problem in your style definition, you have to call the style defined with an "@":

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
  </style>

  <!-- Application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/AppBaseTheme">
  </style>
</resources>
```

`@style/AppBaseTheme` means here that the system will call the style named `AppBaseTheme` in your file styles.xml.

Comment: Already tried that and the result is the same. Also see the screenshot, in the AndroidManifest.xml there are similar errors, e.g. it can't find @drawable/ic_launcher. It compiles and runs so I think the code is correct, it's just the code inspection of Android Studio that doesn't know about those resources I think.

Comment: After cleaning, while AS is rebuilding, everything seems to be ok, as soon as the (gradle) background task is finished, the inspection kicks in again and complains.

Comment: I modified my answer, I changed the way you called the parent theme `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`, you can have a try. For the error on your drawable, have you checked if the drawable is in all your drawable folders?

Comment: Tried it with the modified answer. Still no luck. It won't even find @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar though Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar works as expected. I say expected because it's the way it's done in the HoloEverywhere Demo.

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you more, I am using Eclipse, and this kind of problem is usually fixed with a whole cleaning of the project. For Android Studio I don't know what could be the reason...

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the problem was solved by closing the project, deleting the .idea folder and all .iml files, cleaning with `./gradlew clean` and reimporting the project. This time I ticked the **auto import** checkbox while importing using the gradle model.

Answer (score 3):

do this :

**1**- go to `android studio’s menu bar` `Build` > **Rebuild Project**

**2**- go to `android studio’s menu bar` `Build` > **Clean Project**

**3**- go to `android studio’s menu bar` `File` > **Invalidate Caches / Restart**

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, what fixed it for me was increasing value of

```
targetSdkVersion 17
```

to

```
targetSdkVersion 18
```

It may happen when you are using dependencies, that expect you to use specific SdkVersion. In My case, I had targetSdkVersion of 25 but appcompat required at least version 26.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried all solutions in this topic and finally passing full package path like this:

`setContentView(com.example.dontknowwhat.R.layout.main_activity)`

helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case it was caused by the fact that I had a module with the same package name of the app module, so Android Studio was recognizing the res folder in the module as the resource of the app module. I solved it in this way:

- changed the package name of the module adding a .feature in the middle;
- created a "feature" folder and copying the package in it for each variant (main, debut, androidTest, test) to match the package name with the files paths;
- fixed each imports;
- invalidated the cache.